# breeze.js v1.4.7 navigation error using entity framework v6.0.2

Tags: javascript, wcf, entity-framework, knockout.js

I'm using breeze.js with ef 5.0, wcf data services 5.6.0, knockout.js 3.0 and everything is working fine.
Last week I tried to update entity framework to version 6.0.2 and there is no way to make the solution working again: every time I receive error only on navigation binding:
es: "text: Soggetti().Cognome"  -> error
es: "text: prova" -> ok

the error say: "Soggetti" is undefined but I can see "Soggetti" object in the json coming from server.

So do You have any suggestion please?

Many thanks
Michele

update 21/12/2013:

server side code -wcf data services using entity framwork 6.0.2:

```
[JSONPSupportBehavior]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
[Serializable]
public partial class Entities : EntityFrameworkDataService<DL.mymap>
{
    // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        // TODO: set rules to indicate which entity sets and service operations are visible, updatable, etc.
        // Examples:
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
        // config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("MyServiceOperation", ServiceOperationRights.All);
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
    }
```

this is the html:

```
<table id="tbl_Legnatico" class="hovered">
        <thead>
            <tr style="font-weight: bold">
                <th>Cod.Pratica</th>
                <th>Data Pratica</th>
                <th>Cognome</th>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Data fine</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: itemsLegnatico" >
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: CodicePratica, click: $parent.selectLegnatico"></td>
                <td data-bind="dateString: DataPratica, click: $parent.selectLegnatico"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: Soggetti().Cognome, click: $parent.selectLegnatico"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: Soggetti().Nome, click: $parent.selectLegnatico"></td>
                <td data-bind="dateString: DataFineValidita, click: $parent.selectLegnatico"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

this is the js query using breeze:

```
function vmLegnaticoSel(searchEntity, searchField, searchValue) {
$("#tbl_Legnatico_dettaglio").attr("style", "display: none;");
$("#tbl_Legnatico").attr("style", "display: block; width: 100%");
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("dataService", "OData");
var dataService = new breeze.DataService({
    serviceName: "http://localhost/BL/Entities.svc",
    hasServerMetadata: true
});
var ms = new breeze.MetadataStore();
managerLegnatico = new breeze.EntityManager({
    dataService: dataService,
    metadataStore: ms
});
var query = null;
switch (searchEntity) {
    case "Soggetti":
        switch (searchField) {
            case "Denominazione":
                query = new breeze.EntityQuery()
                   .from("Legnatico")
                   .expand("Soggetti")
                   .where("Soggetti.Denominazione", "startsWith", searchValue);
                break;
            default:
        }
        break;
    case "Legnatico":
        if (searchValue == '')
            searchValue = -111;
        switch (searchField) {
            case "CodicePratica":
                query = new breeze.EntityQuery()
                   .from("Legnatico")
                   .expand("Soggetti")
                   .where("CodicePratica", "eq", searchValue);
                break;
            default:
        }
        break;
    default:
}
$('#dialog').jqmShow();
managerLegnatico.executeQuery(query).then(function (data) {
      vmLegnatico.itemsLegnatico(data.results);        
    }).fail(function (e) {
        alert(e);
});
```

}

this is the mvvm:

```
function vmLegnaticoInit()
    {
        vmLegnatico = (function () {
            self.itemsLegnatico = ko.observableArray();
            self.itemsSoggetti = ko.observableArray();
            self.selectedLegnatico = ko.observable(),
            self.deletedLegnatico = ko.observable(),
            self.selectLegnatico = function (p) {
                selectedLegnatico(p);                 
            self.saveEdit = function (p) {;

                mymap.managerSaveChanges(managerLegnatico);



            };
            return {
                saveEdit: saveEdit,
                itemsLegnatico: itemsLegnatico,
                itemsSoggetti: itemsSoggetti,
                selectedLegnatico: selectedLegnatico,
                selectLegnatico: selectLegnatico,
        })();
        ko.applyBindings(vmLegnatico);
    }
```

Comment: Please add the code you are working with

Comment: Hi Andy, if I change entity framework from v.6 (EntityFrameworkDataService<DL.mymap>) to v5 (DataService<DL.mymap>) everything work ok.